# php SplObjectStorage Detach() not working

Tags: php, object, storage

I have found an error in PHP SplObjectStorage Detach method. Where it's working fine in removing an object but if the object comes one another it skip the next one.

Example:

```
$s = new SplObjectStorage();

$o1 = new StdClass;
$o2 = new StdClass;
$o3 = new StdClass;

$o1->attr = '1';
$o2->attr = '2';
$o3->attr = '3';

$s->attach($o1);
$s->attach($o2);
$s->attach($o3);

echo 'Removing Objects...<pre>';
var_dump($s->count());
foreach ($s as $obj) {
   var_dump($obj->attr);
   if($obj->attr == 2 || $obj->attr == 1) {
       echo "Deleting...".$obj->attr;
       $s->detach($obj);
   }
}

echo 'Checking Objects....';
var_dump($s->count());
foreach ($s as $obj) {
   var_dump($obj->attr);
}
```

and it gives me this result. which shouldn't be, because i want to delete Object (attr == 1) and Object (attr == 2) both. Detach() method only delete first object, then skip the next one and then loop.

```
Removing Objects...

int 3

string '1' (length=1)

Deleting...1

string '3' (length=1)


Checking Objects....

int 2

string '2' (length=1)

string '3' (length=1)
```

** Object ($o2->attr = '2') should also be deleted, which is not because skip in the first loop.

Comment: why negative vote..... if i didn't explain in question. you can check the code (code don't need human language). it's clear in the code i detach two objects but it only remove one object which shouldn't be....

Comment: Hi @hakre, have you any idea about this....

Comment: @Alon, plz help me to get out of this problem.......

Answer (score 2):

I have found a bug in SplObjectStorage Detach() method which are:

> Detaching the current entry from the storage prevents SplObjectStorage::next() to operate.

so by preventing the Next object when Detach() execute, the iteration will never reach the second (next) stdClass object. SplObjectStorage::next() obviously relies on the current element to be valid.

> To avoid this bug in SplObjectStorage class we needs to call next()
>   before calling detach().

Hope this will help other users not to face this problem and not to waste their time...